# Generating sequence in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a sequence using a SQL query.

The sequence needs to be like this:

> 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...

Comment: One option would be a recursive query.

Comment: Would there be any Better optimized Query for it?

Comment: If you know the required maximum value, you can simply use a values clause (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Should the output be a table or a string?

Comment: It should be a table

Comment: @user10747759 . . . For this problem, I wouldn't be surprised if a recursive CTE were the *best* way to solve the problem.  Otherwise, you have to create an intermediate table with "too many rows" and hope the optimizer does the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use any recursion, then there is [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455511/formula-for-the-nth-term-of-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4-5) from our friends on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) website. The sequence must start with value `0`.

Use a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) to generate as much numbers as required (I opted for a 1000 numbers).

```
WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT FLOOR((1 + SQRT(1 + 8 * (t.n - 1))) / 2)
FROM Tally t;
```

---

**EDIT**: There is another, easier formula. Here, the sequence must start with value `1`.

```
WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT ROUND(SQRT(2 * t.n), 0) AS SEQUENCE
FROM Tally t;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0d244e3a1ca84ec034397ed452b0d0e) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

In a T-SQL stored procedure, you could try this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sequence
    @count INT
AS  
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @j INT = 0
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    a INT
);

WHILE @i < @count
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @j = 0
    
    WHILE @j < @i
    BEGIN
        SET @j = @j + 1
        INSERT INTO @tempTable (@i)
    END
END
SELECT a FROM @tablename
GO
```

By using `WHILE` loops, it is possible to count up to a maximum value and `INSERT` the counts into a temporary table.